# Are desktop wallets transferable?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, multibit, wallet.dat, wallet-import

I know you can make a transaction across the blockchain to move your Bitcoins from say [Bitcoin-QT](http://bitcoin.org/en/download) to [Multibit](https://multibit.org/), but is it possible to import my wallet.dat file from Bitcoin-QT to another desktop wallet without preforming a transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possible but importing private keys would work better.

All you need to import an address to a new wallet is the private key. Get the private keys of your addresses from the QT client and import them into Multibit.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply copy .bitcoin/wallet.dat to another place, and use it like HOME dir for bitcoind/bitcoin-qt.

It is like a copy the whole bitcoind data.

Other files in .bitcoin/ directory are just a logs and configs with database, which will be downloaded from network automatically by your new client program.